# Class 'Storage' not found in lumen while using aws s3 instance for storage

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, laravel-5, lumen

I am using AWS s3 instance to store all my files . but it is showing class Storage not found.I have imported all the required namespaces and classes.

```
use Storage;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\Filesystem;
```

function logic goes like this.

```
 public function insertAdvertisement($input)
{
    $advertisment = new AdvertisingBanner;

    $image = $input['image'];

    $imageName = "Banner" . time() . '.' . $input['image']->getClientOriginalExtension();

    /*$input['image']->move(
            base_path() . '/public/uploads/advertiseImages/', $imageName
    );*/

    $disk = \Storage::disk('s3');
    $filePath ='/public/uploads/advertiseImages/'.$imageName;
    $s3->put($filePath, file_get_contents($image), 'public');

    $advertisment->title = $input['title'];

    $advertisment->image = $imageName;

    $advertisment->added_by = $input['added_by'];

    $advertisment->save();

    return $advertisment->save();

}
```

Comment: @do you have included laravel storage package?

Answer (score 5):

Lumen 5.2+ removed the global class alias for the `Storage` facade. Change your `use` statement to:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
```

And then in your code:

```
// no starting slash; rely on use statement
$disk = Storage::disk('s3');
```